# Not grab group match in Ruby Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to break down the following string:

```
"@command Text1 @command2 Text2"
```

in Ruby. I want to take out "Text1" and "Text2" in an array. To do this I am using the scan method and using this:

```
text.scan(/@* (.*?)(@|$)/)
```

However, when run, the script is pulling the @ symbol in the middle as a separate match (presumably because the parenthesis are used in Ruby to indicate what string you want to pull out of the input):

```
Text1
@ 
Text2
```

My question is, how can I pull out Text1 and Text2 bearing in mind the expression needs to stop matching at both "@" and the end of a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a non-capturing group use ?:

```
text.scan(/@* (.*?)(?:@|$)/)
```

As a sidenote, your regular expression looks like it might contain an error. Perhaps you meant this instead?

```
text.scan(/@\w+ (\w+)(?= @|$)/)
```

The difference is that your expression matches on `" foo"`, which I guess is not intentional.

Answer (score 1):

```
text.scan(/@* (.*?)(?:@|$)/)'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your regex, you don't need the parentheses around '@|$'. The following will accomplish the same thing without the '@' being returned in a separate match group:

```
text.scan(/@* (.*?)[@\$]/)
```

Since you're looking only for a single character in that group, the square brackets will match any one character within them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
text.scan(/@[^\s]* ([^@]*)/)
```

Answer (score 0):

How does this regex look?
http://rubular.com/regexes/13264